# Casting the Expression.Property result

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees

How do I create a cast when creating an `Expression` tree dynamically?

The problem is, I have a property of type `string`:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to generically create a strongly typed lambda expression representing a delegate which returns an `object` instead of a `string` (`Expression<Func<T, object>>`).

Right now I am doing this:

```
private static Expression<Func<T, object>> CreateIdQuery()
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    PropertyInfo idProperty = type.GetProperty("Id");
    ParameterExpression lambdaParam = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
    MemberExpression body = Expression.Property(lambdaParam, idProperty);
    LambdaExpression expr = Expression.Lambda(body, lambdaParam);
    return (Expression<Func<T, object>>)expr;
}
```

But it throws an exception in the last line (I cannot cast `Expression<Func<Test, string>>` to `Expression<Func<Test, object>>`).

How do i cast the body of the expression (I am presuming the `MemberExpression` part needs to be cast into an `object`)?

Comment: When creating the lambda, since you know what the types are, it would be cleaner to use one of the [generic overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda.aspx).  Though the `Convert` expression would still be needed if `Id` is a value type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051.aspx).

```
private static Expression<Func<T, object>> CreateIdQuery()
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    PropertyInfo idProperty = type.GetProperty("Id");
    ParameterExpression lambdaParam = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
    MemberExpression body = Expression.Property(lambdaParam, idProperty);
    UnaryExpression converted = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object));
    LambdaExpression expr = Expression.Lambda(converted, lambdaParam);
    return (Expression<Func<T, object>>)expr;
}
```